# Set the width of annotation text in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to set an specific width for my text annotation in ggplot. For example, I want the first annotation to go from `x = 0` to `x = 40`, and the second annotation from `x = 50` to `x = 90`. In other words I need to make these annotation fit the spaces between 0 and 40, and between 50 and 90.

I also want the text be well aligned.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

df <- tibble(x = 1:100, y = 1:100)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))+ geom_blank() +

  annotate(geom = 'text', x = 0, y = 50, hjust = 0, vjust = 0,
           label = 'Shortly after his arrival at Real Madrid in July 2018, ESPN journalist Dermot Corrigan described Vinícius
as a "zippy left winger or second striker". El Mundo described him "A player who is forever tormented,
teetering on the edge, on that invisible line between genius and ridicule. Judgment always hangs over
him, a winger unable to make his legs and feet move in unison, but he never gives up and that is a great
quality. A versatile player, although he is usually deployed on the left flank, he is capable of playing
anywhere along the front line,  and has also been used on the right or in the centre. ',
 size = 3,
color  ='black')+
  annotate(geom = 'text', x = 50, y = 50, hjust = 0, vjust = 0,
           label = 'Shortly after his arrival at Real Madrid in July 2018, ESPN journalist Dermot Corrigan described Vinícius
as a "zippy left winger or second striker". El Mundo described him "A player who is forever tormented,
teetering on the edge, on that invisible line between genius and ridicule. Judgment always hangs over
him, a winger unable to make his legs and feet move in unison, but he never gives up and that is a great
quality. A versatile player, although he is usually deployed on the left flank, he is capable of playing
anywhere along the front line,  and has also been used on the right or in the centre. ',
size = 3,
color  ='black')
```

Is this possible with ggplot2? Is there any other package that help me to do this?

Comment: I get an "unused arguments" error with that code.

Comment: @IRTFM sorry. I edited the question. It was the font-family

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ggtext::geom_textbox()` to display annotations, and turn off the actual box part. Note that you need to know your x-limits in advance to calculate the correct width of the box in normalised parental coordinates (npc units). In this case* if you want from 0 to 40 on a scale of 1-100, you need to calculate (40-0)/((100 - 1) * 1.1). The 1.1 is the default scale expansion factor (5% on both sides). Added some vertical lines to show that text is inside those bounds.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
#> Warning: package 'ggtext' was built under R version 4.1.1

df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 1:100)

width <- (40-0)/((100 - 1) * 1.1)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))+ geom_blank() +
  
  annotate(geom = 'text_box', x = 0, y = 70, hjust = 0, vjust = 1,
           label = 'Shortly after his arrival at Real Madrid in July 2018, ESPN journalist Dermot Corrigan described Vinícius
as a "zippy left winger or second striker". El Mundo described him "A player who is forever tormented,
teetering on the edge, on that invisible line between genius and ridicule. Judgment always hangs over
him, a winger unable to make his legs and feet move in unison, but he never gives up and that is a great
quality. A versatile player, although he is usually deployed on the left flank, he is capable of playing
anywhere along the front line,  and has also been used on the right or in the centre. ',
           family = 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', size = 3, width = unit(width, "npc"),
           color  ='black', fill = NA, box.colour = NA, box.padding = margin())+
  annotate(geom = 'text_box', x = 50, y = 70, hjust = 0, vjust = 1,
           label = 'Shortly after his arrival at Real Madrid in July 2018, ESPN journalist Dermot Corrigan described Vinícius
as a "zippy left winger or second striker". El Mundo described him "A player who is forever tormented,
teetering on the edge, on that invisible line between genius and ridicule. Judgment always hangs over
him, a winger unable to make his legs and feet move in unison, but he never gives up and that is a great
quality. A versatile player, although he is usually deployed on the left flank, he is capable of playing
anywhere along the front line,  and has also been used on the right or in the centre. ',
           family = 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', size = 3, width = unit(width, "npc"),
           color  ='black', fill = NA, box.colour = NA, box.padding = margin()) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0, 40, 50, 90))
#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database
#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font
#> family not found in Windows font database
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

* should actually be (40 - 0) / ((100 - 0) * 1.1) because I didn't take into account that the `x = 0` of the annotation affected the scale.

Comment: Nice! And also If I want to reduce the widh the text will adjust itself. Right?

Comment: Yes, try resizing your plot window for example, it should fit the available space.

Comment: Thanks for your time @teunbrand!

Comment: @teunbrand, Nice! Adding text with a certain span to ggplot should be done easier? Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean with span (?) Do you mean text wrapping with a fixed number of characters?

Comment: @teunbrand. thanks for your reply. I mean to set the length of the text with xmin and xmax like for other geoms. So I am not sure if that is naive question, but it was my first idea to solve the question?

Comment: Yeah I was looking for that option too, but I couldn't find it in the docs. However, I saw that the `width` takes a `unit()` object, which you can reverse engineer what it should be if you know the x-axis in advance. I couldn't find an issue on GH for this, so maybe its worth it to put in a feature request?

Answer (score 3):

Using `ggfittext::geom_fit_text` and its `xmin` and `xmax` aesthetics. Adjust the text with `place` and remove the (default) padding with `padding.x`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfittext)

ggplot() +
  geom_fit_text(aes(xmin = c(0, 50), xmax = c(40, 90),
                    y = 50,
                    label = c('Shortly after his arrival at Real Madrid in July 2018, ESPN journalist Dermot Corrigan described Vinícius
as a "zippy left winger or second striker". El Mundo described him "A player who is forever tormented,
teetering on the edge, on that invisible line between genius and ridicule. Judgment always hangs over
him, a winger unable to make his legs and feet move in unison, but he never gives up and that is a great
quality. A versatile player, although he is usually deployed on the left flank, he is capable of playing
anywhere along the front line,  and has also been used on the right or in the centre. ',
                              'Shortly after his arrival at Real Madrid in July 2018, ESPN journalist Dermot Corrigan described Vinícius
as a "zippy left winger or second striker". El Mundo described him "A player who is forever tormented,
teetering on the edge, on that invisible line between genius and ridicule. Judgment always hangs over
him, a winger unable to make his legs and feet move in unison, but he never gives up and that is a great
quality. A versatile player, although he is usually deployed on the left flank, he is capable of playing
anywhere along the front line,  and has also been used on the right or in the centre. ')),
                reflow = TRUE, place = "left", padding.x = grid::unit(0, "mm")) +
  xlim(0, 100)
```

[image]